# fstream в Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, fstream, файловый-ввод-вывод

Пытаюсь я считать число из файла и сразу же вывести его в консоль, а выводиться неинициализированный участок памяти, а все данные из файла удаляются. Я не могу найти где это настроить (Visual studio 2017).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream fin("Text.txt");
ofstream fout("Text.txt");

int main()
{

   int x;
  fin >> x;
  cout << x;


}
```

Comment: Уберите эту строку - `ofstream fout("Text.txt");` - зачем она вам сейчас? Тем более что она и убивает ваш файл, открывая его для перезаписи и, по всей видимости, мешая открыть его для чтения... Да и лучше бы перенести `ifstream fin("Text.txt");` в `main` - просто поближе к использованию...

Comment: И ещё хорошо бы проверять открылся ли файл вообще.